# Binding to a RelativeSource Self in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, binding, self, relativesource

I am trying to bind a value of a slider control to a property that is in the same control:

```
 <Slider 
        Value="{Binding Path=ValueProperty, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Name="slider1"  />
```

but it doesn't bind to a "ValuePropery"...
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why you want to bind it to itself?

Comment: Not sure what he is trying to do, but binding to itself is valid. For example if I want to make button invisible if command is disabled.  <Button x:Name="cmdSave" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" Content="Save"  Width="75" Height="23"
                            Visibility="{Binding IsEnabled, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self},  Converter={StaticResource trueToVisibleConverter}}"/>

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure what you mean by *the same control*.
If you are creating your user control and it contains a property named ValueProperty that you've defined (i.e. in code behind of the control), you can try the code:

```
<Slider 
    Value="{Binding ElementName=LayoutRoot Path=Parent.ValueProperty}"
    Name="slider1"  />
```

This solution requires you to have your root control in your user control to be named `LayoutRoot` (it's the default).

Answer (score 4):

As I understand you are trying to bind Slider Value property to itself, if that is the case then you inccorectly determining Path of Binding change your XAML as follow:

```
<Slider Value="{Binding Path=Value, RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}"
        Name="slider1"  />
```

Answer (score 1):

If you mean a property of the current page then check this discussion:
[WP7 Binding to Local Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4912452/wp7-binding-to-local-variable/4912570#4912570)

If you mean a property of the Slider then you can use TemplateBinding:

```
<Slider  Value="{TemplateBinding ValueProperty}" Name="slider1"  />
```

Hope this will help you.

Comment: TemplateBinding can be used in templates only