# WP7 Binding to Local Variable

Tags: silverlight, variables, binding, windows-phone-7, local

I have a UI element whose color I'd like to set based on a local variable in the page (well actually in a module, but I can move it to the page).

I see in WPF one can bind a UI element to a local variable by making the variable a property and setting the binding *RelativeSource* to the parent class using *FindAncestor*:

[WPF Binding to local variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1481130/wpf-binding-to-local-variable)

Unfortunately Silverlight doesn't seem to support *FindAncestor* mode.

Any possible solution, or do I have to create an instance of a custom class and such just for this one variable?

Answer (score 7):

Ive been jumping from Silverlight to WPF a lot over the last few weeks, so the following idea may or may not fly.

Does your page have the name property set on it? If not, set it (x:Name="MyPage").

then you can do:

```
Fill="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=MyProperty}"
```

Give that a try (just off the top of my head)

Comment: +1, I was about to post the same answer.  ElementName binding is the usual (weaker) workaround for lack of FindAncestor.

FWIW, FindAncestor binding is coming in Silverlight 5, so hopefully this eventually makes its way to the phone.

Comment: Hmm gave it a shot with an integer property to keep it simple.  Named the page "MyPage," then in the UI element, put:
`<RotateTransform Angle="{Binding ElementName=MyPage, Path=gDirection}" />`.  In the page code, I have:
`Property gDirection As Integer = 45`.  This throws an exception on load.  If I replace the binding with 45, it works fine, so looks like the binding's not working...

Comment: So it works fine with just a number, but when the binding is inserted, it gives a XamlParseException:

System.Windows.Markup.XamlParseException occurred
  Message=AG_E_PARSER_BAD_PROPERTY_VALUE [Line: 45 Position: 42]
  LineNumber=45
  LinePosition=42
  StackTrace:
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.CheckHResult(UInt32 hr)
       at MS.Internal.XcpImports.UIElement_Measure(UIElement element, Size availableSize)
       at System.Windows.UIElement.Measure(Size availableSize)
       at Microsoft.Phone.Controls.Maps.MapLayer.MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
...

Comment: For reference, this is an item within a template for a pushpin for a map control.

Comment: I was able to use this approach for toggling the visibility of an element base on the page orientation. I did however have to implement System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged in the page for the binding to pick up the changes.